# How to select my xml file as data source for a data view

Tags: search-results, dataview

I am using sp 2010. I have a page with a search result webpart. Inside this webpart I have some xslt for the look and feel. I would like to add a new column to my search results.

I found this blog how to customize the search results with xslt in sharepoint designer. I am stuck on the step to add the xml file as a datasource to a data view.

How can I select my own xml file as a datasource for a data view?

**BLOG:**

http://zimmergren.net/technical/moss-2007-customize-the-search-result-using-xslt-part-3-customize-using-sharepoint-designer-2007

Here another one:

http://office.microsoft.com/sq-al/sharepoint-designer-help/create-data-views-in-sharepoint-designer-HA101631628.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it by my self. On the left menu you have the link "Data Sources". Here you can add an xml data source which will be visible in the datasources list.